# Could not enable discrete graphics card

Tags: linux, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, parrot-os

**Briefly describe your issue below:**
I was following this documentation(https://docs.parrotlinux.org/info/gpu-drivers/) for installing proprietary Nvidia driver.
**`Issue:`** When I had test run with `optirun glxgears` I had no errors and it worked **but** when I followed whole documentation(yes I did create those files and appended the content that instructed) and reboot the system then I ran  **optirun glxgears** I got this error.

```
 ____ $optirun -vv glxgears
[ 1356.734285] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 1356.734992] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[ 1356.734997] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 1356.734999] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 1356.735001] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 1356.735003] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
[ 1356.735005] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 1356.735007] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[ 1356.735009] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[ 1356.735011] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[ 1356.735013] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[ 1356.735099] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[ 1356.735306] [INFO]Response: No - error: Could not enable discrete graphics card

[ 1356.735313] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not enable discrete graphics card

[ 1356.735318] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[ 1356.735347] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[ 1356.735351] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

**What version of Parrot are you running?**

Its fresh install of parrot and up to date.
Linux parrot 5.7.0-2parrot2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.7.10-1parrot2 (2020-07-31) x86_64 GNU/Linux

**If there are any error messages or relevant logs, post them below:**

```
____ $sudo dmesg | grep bbswitch
[   41.551342] bbswitch: version 0.8
[   41.551353] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[   41.551367] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[   41.551603] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[   41.551807] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[   41.553569] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[  352.141180] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[  930.208956] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[ 1225.390955] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[ 1350.309887] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[ 1354.342766] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[ 1356.747766] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[ 2167.234057] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[ 2186.187844] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[ 2405.406211] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
```

.

```
   ______$ lspci -v                                                                                                                                                                                            
            00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])                                                                                  
                    DeviceName: Onboard - Video                                                                                                                                                           
                    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)                                                                                                                                             
                    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127, IOMMU group 2                                                                                                                     
                    Memory at a2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]                                                                                                                              
                    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]                                                                                                                                 
                    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]                                                                                                                                                           
                    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]                                                                                                                            
                    Capabilities: <access denied>                                                                                                                                                         
                    Kernel driver in use: i915                                                                                                                                                            
                    Kernel modules: i915
```

.

```
______$ lspci -v 

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
        Kernel modules: nvidia
```

I have also tried by writing in '/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf' file where "Driver=" placed "Driver=nvidia". Reboot the system. Still doesnt work.

**UPDATE #1:**

My laptop model is Dell G3 3579.

```
____ $optirun -vv glxgears -info
[  471.923260] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  471.923960] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[  471.923980] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[  471.923982] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  471.923984] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[  471.923986] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
[  471.923988] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[  471.923990] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[  471.923991] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[  471.923993] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[  471.923995] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[  471.924045] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[  471.924142] [INFO]Response: No - error: Could not enable discrete graphics card

[  471.924146] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not enable discrete graphics card

[  471.924148] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[  471.924152] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[  471.924155] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

Comment: What is you laptop model? What's the result of running `optirun glxgears -info`? Try also [this advice](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/issues/177#issuecomment-497967629).

Comment: @harrymc My laptop model is Dell G3 3579. and I have updated my post with o/p of "optirun glxgears -info". I'm working on the advice you said but I dont think it will work because I have already tried it before reinstalling the system. Anyway I'll update you on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is very frequent and with heaps of solutions.
Bumblebee is said to be incompatible with many models of Dell.
One of the following might work for you:

- Run without TLP
- `lspci | grep "NVIDIA" | cut -b -8` and append the output to `RUNTIME_PM_BLACKLIST` in `/etc/default/tlp`
- Use Bumblebee without bbswitch, so Intel is used by default and use `optirun`
  for the Nvidia
- In `/etc/modprobe.d/bbswitch.conf` uncomment the line:

  ```
    #options bbswitch load_state=0 unload_state=1
  ```
- Use instead [optimus-manager](https://github.com/Askannz/optimus-manager).

Comment: Note: As I don't have your environment, I can't help with details.

Comment: I have bookmarked this if I get into this sort of problem I will do as you have answered. But the problem seems to gone when I undo everything from the documentation and did everything again and its worked fine now. I guess I was having problem because in "lspci -v" you can see I have error there. I had that error because just after I finished documentation first time and reboot system I had few nvidia related updates maybe thats why I had that error and everything went downhill from that. But now doing documentation again its working as intended. Thanks for replying ! HGD <3